# when using setstate, can I use the simple object like the following?

Tags: reactjs

I encounter some code recently which use setstate. if I initialize a as 0

```
  constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                a:0
            }
        }
```

Can I use like the following?

```
let a = 6
this.setstate ({a})
```

if yes, where could I find the documentation of this kind of usage?

or I have to use

```
this.setstate({a:6})
```

Comment: Could you show some code of both usages? It's very hard to understand what you mean from the current question.

Comment: is it clear now?

Comment: It's clearer now, thanks. You can't to `this.setState(a)`, but you can do `this.setState({ a })` which you might be referring to, as [outlined here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

Comment: sorry, change the question. why the two style is same?

Comment: *"if yes, where could I find the documentation of this kind of usage?"* Always on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ecmascript 2015](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) introduced a new shorthand syntax for object initialization, so both ways of writing it will give the same result.

```
let a = 6;
this.setState({ a }); // Shorthand syntax for writing this.setState({ a: a });
```

Answer (score 0):

You still have to pass an object to setState.

However, you can make the object key be variable!

```
let id = "a"
let val = 6
this.setstate ({[id]:val})
```